# ArcGIS Javascript in AngularJS App - Error Loading Modules

Tags: angularjs, dojo, require, arcgis-js-api

I have an AngularJS application which is using the [ArcGIS API](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/) for JavaScript to display a map.

I have been using individual require statements such as:

```
var esriMap = require("esri/map");
```

This has worked fine for all modules EXCEPT for [Dojo layout Dijits](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/).  When I try to add a require statement like this:

```
var Scalebar = require("esri/dijit/Scalebar");
```

I get the following error:

> `Error: undefinedModule(…) "Error: undefinedModule
>       at Error (native)
>       at d (http://js.arcgis.com/3.12/init.js:15:382)
>       at La (http://js.arcgis.com/3.12/init.js:24:296)
>       at r (http://js.arcgis.com/3.12/init.js:15:476)`

I would like to keep using the individual require statements if possible.  Is there any reason why I would be getting this error only on the dijit modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single-argument `require` only works for modules that have already been loaded.  Judging by the `undefinedModule` error, you're trying to use single-argument `require` on modules that were never loaded.  To reference modules that have not yet been loaded, you need to use the standard AMD require syntax:

```
require([
    'dijit/layout/StackContainer',
    ...
], function (StackContainer, ...) {
    ...
});
```

It's usually simplest to always use this format.  (It could also be considered more reliable, since otherwise you're likely relying on assumptions that the modules you're using have already been loaded, whether directly or indirectly as dependencies.)

Comment: Thanks Ken.  I'm still not entirely clear why the single-argument require was failing, but the standard AMD is working.

Comment: Some dojo modules are already dependencies included in Esri's pre-built `init` layer, and thus those will have already been registered into the loader's cache and can be used via `require(mid)` with no issue.  Others that have not been registered in the cache yet will need to be loaded via `require(deps, factory)`.  Generally the former is only advisable when you're sure something's already been loaded and don't already have a direct reference to it.

Comment: BTW - @KenFranqueiro you've given me [an idea of how to improve angular-esri-map](https://github.com/Esri/angular-esri-map/issues/144)

Answer (score 2):

Also, I don't know if you've seen this, but Esri does have some angular modules that help integrate maps into Angular apps:

https://github.com/Esri/angular-esri-map

That includes a service called `esriLoader` that wraps Dojo's require and allows you to either pass a callback that will receive the modules or get a promise that is resolved as an array with the modules.